# Issue with RSA crate Rust

Tags: rust, cryptography, rsa

I'm a beginner in Rust and I'm facing an issue with the RSA crate in Rust.
I'm trying to verify a signature. My code is as simple as :

```
use rsa::{RsaPublicKey};

use rsa::pkcs8::DecodePublicKey;
fn main() {
    let pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtsQsUV8QpqrygsY+2+JC
    Q6Fw8/omM71IM2N/R8pPbzbgOl0p78MZGsgPOQ2HSznjD0FPzsH8oO2B5Uftws04
    LHb2HJAYlz25+lN5cqfHAfa3fgmC38FfwBkn7l582UtPWZ/wcBOnyCgb3yLcvJrX
    yrt8QxHJgvWO23ITrUVYszImbXQ67YGS0YhMrbixRzmo2tpm3JcIBtnHrEUMsT0N
    fFdfsZhTT8YbxBvA8FdODgEwx7u/vf3J9qbi4+Kv8cvqyJuleIRSjVXPsIMnoejI
    n04APPKIjpMyQdnWlby7rNyQtE4+CV+jcFjqJbE/Xilcvqxt6DirjFCvYeKYl1uH
    LwIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    let _public_key = RsaPublicKey::from_public_key_pem(pem).unwrap();

}
```

However I'm getting an error saying that :

```
---- tests::add_public_key_verif stdout ----
thread 'tests::add_public_key_verif' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Asn1(Error { kind: Pem(PostEncapsulationBoundary), position: None })', src/lib.rs:136:40
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

In cargo.toml, I have :

```
[package]
name = "hello_cargo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rsa ="0.6.1"
```

The issue seams to come from the public key generation from the PEM.

Do you know a solution for fix this issue ?

Comment: I cannot compile this code because of missing dependencies and types. Please create a minimal example that we can compile, and include the dependencies you are using.

Comment: @cdhowie. Done, I changed my question with a minimal code that compile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is the problem here. The whitespace at the beginning of the line is part of the string value, but that's not valid PEM encoding. To fix it, remove the leading whitespace:

```
fn main() {
    let pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtsQsUV8QpqrygsY+2+JC
Q6Fw8/omM71IM2N/R8pPbzbgOl0p78MZGsgPOQ2HSznjD0FPzsH8oO2B5Uftws04
LHb2HJAYlz25+lN5cqfHAfa3fgmC38FfwBkn7l582UtPWZ/wcBOnyCgb3yLcvJrX
yrt8QxHJgvWO23ITrUVYszImbXQ67YGS0YhMrbixRzmo2tpm3JcIBtnHrEUMsT0N
fFdfsZhTT8YbxBvA8FdODgEwx7u/vf3J9qbi4+Kv8cvqyJuleIRSjVXPsIMnoejI
n04APPKIjpMyQdnWlby7rNyQtE4+CV+jcFjqJbE/Xilcvqxt6DirjFCvYeKYl1uH
LwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    let _public_key = RsaPublicKey::from_public_key_pem(pem).unwrap();

}
```

Alternatively, consider putting the PEM key data in a separate file and using the [`include_str!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro to load it into a variable.  This keeps the key data separate from the program logic as well as making the indentation issue irrelevant.  (Note that this happens at compile time; there is no runtime overhead to this approach.)

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly :). Not sure I can use the include_str! because the pem should in fact be an argument in a function.